# PHP - Redirecting after login based on url query

Tags: php, redirect

I'm developing a user site in php. What I want to do, is allow people to use a ?return_to url variable to get back to the page they were on before they were asked to log in (for example, if they were on `/me.php`, then they will be redirected to login, and the url will be `login.php?return_to=me.php`.. I want to redirect to me.php after login.).

Currently, the way my system checks for login submission on the homepage is with the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    if($advena->Login())
    {
        $advena->RedirectToURL("/");
    }
}
```

When I try to use

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?return_to") !== false){

    $location .= "?return_to=" . urlencode($_GET["return_to"]);

    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        if($fgmembersite->Login())
        {
            $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL($location);
        }
    }

} else {

    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        if($fgmembersite->Login())
        {
            $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("/");
        }
    }
}
```

It always redirects to `"/"` regardless of the presence of `?return_to`. Here is the redirect php:

```
function RedirectToURL($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help anyone can provide :)

Answer (score 0):

### members.php - sample page

```
<?php
    // set the return url value
    $_SESSION['return_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // redirect if not logged in
    if (!not_logged_in()) {
        header('Location: /login.php?return_to=' . rawurlencode($_SESSION['return_url']));
        exit;
    }

    // checks if the user is logged in
    function not_logged_in() {
        return !isset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
    }
?>
```

### login.php - login page

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    // do more...
    // redirect
    if (success()) {
        // set a session for logged in user
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = sha1(time() . rand(0, 99999));

        if (isset($_GET['return_to'], $_SESSION['return_url'])) {
            $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL('/process.php?ret=' . urldecode($_GET['return_to']));
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL('/process.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

### process.php - login processor

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['return_to'], $_SESSION['return_url'])) {

    # set: return url
    $continue_url = rawurldecode($_GET['return_to']);

    # do: redirect to the specified page
    header("Location: {$continue_url}");

    unset($_SESSION['return_url']);

    # do: redirect with message
    exit('Redirecting...');
}
else {
    header('Location: /members.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Nope.. Still redirects to `'/'` for me

Comment: Still not working. When i go to members.php, it instantly signs me out (although it does set the return  url).. Even then, when I sign back in, it redirects me to process.php and then back to index.php regardless of the callback url.

Comment: updated my answer. it signs you out immediately because you did not set a logged in session for the users identity. on the members page, I've set the `not_logged_in()` function which checks the users session